# text highlight in markdown

Tags: syntax, markdown

Within a Markdown editor I want to support text highlight, not in the sense of code highlighting, but the type of highlighting people do on books.

In code oriented sites people `can use backquotes` for a grey background, normally inline code within a paragraph. However on books there is the **marker pen** for normal text within a paragraph. That is the classical black text on yellow background.

Is there any syntax within Markdown (or its variants) to specify that the user want that type of highlight? I want to preserve the backquotes syntax for code related marking, but also want a way to enable highlighted user text

My first thought is just using double backquotes, since triple backquotes are reserved for code blocks. I am just wondering if other implementations have already decided a syntax for it... I would also appreciate if someone could justify if this is a very bad idea.

Comment: I agree. I'd like to implement something like the back tick. Something simple for data entry/end users (that doesn't involve writing html)

Answer (score 200):

As the markdown documentation states, it is fine to use HTML if you need a feature that is not part of Markdown.

HTML5 supports

```html
<mark>Marked text</mark>
```

Else you can use span as suggested by Rad Lexus

```html
<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">Marked text</span>
```

Comment: Note that Github does not render the inline style correctly.

Comment: The `mark` tag can also take a different background color (default is bright yellow). That is--`<mark style="background-color: lightblue">Marked text</mark>` also works :)

Comment: The `<mark>` one is the only one that works in Google Colaboratory since it drops all `style`s from inline HTML for whatever reason...

Comment: @Ini so what is the correct syntax for github markdown then?

Comment: @pcko1: Idk, maybe it is simply not supported

Comment: I like it, it works well with the Markdown previewer from VSCode.

Comment: `<mark>` doesn't work for me when viewing in GitHub the file Readme.MD.

Answer (score 50):

I'm late to the party but it seems like a couple of markdown platforms ([Quilt](http://tmthydvnprt.com/quilt/news/markdown_syntax.html) & [iA Writer](https://ia.net/writer/support/general/markdown-guide)) are using a double equal to show highlighting.

```
==highlight==
```

Comment: https://obsidian.md/ also use the `==higlight==` syntax, which is quiet handy, hope it makes it to the CommonMark spec.

Comment: also works on [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for markdowns

Comment: This also works for [HackMD](https://hackmd.io/)

Comment: The problem is GitHub does not support it yet.

Comment: 2023 - Stiil does not work with GitHub inside tables

Comment: This also works in Logseq.

Comment: Seems Like VS code also doesn't support it.. Although the <mark> tag does

Comment: Typora uses ==this== for highlighting as well.

Answer (score 24):

[Typora](https://typora.io/) is also using double equal for highlighting. It would be nice it that becomes a CommonMark standard, as mentioned by DirtyF. It would be nice for those who use it frequently, since it is only 4 repeated chars: ==highlight==

If you want the option to use multiple editors, it may be best to stick with `<mark>highlight</mark>` for now, as answered by Matthias.

Here is the [latest spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#why-is-a-spec-needed-) from CommonMark, "which attempts to specify Markdown syntax unambiguously". Currently "highlighting" is not included.

Editors using ==highlight== from comments mentioned previously:

- Typora
- Obsidian
- Quilt
- IA Writer

Feel free to add to this list.

Comment: Note: In Typora you must enable double equals for highlighting in Preferences -> Markdown

Comment: This also works in Logseq.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Grave accent (backtick) ` to highlight text in markdown

`Highlighted text`

Also works with VS Code extension [markdownlint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint)

Comment: It is actually used for formatting code, not for highlighting text.

Answer (score 6):

### Grey-colored Higlighting Solution

A possible solution is to use the **<code>** element:
This solution works really well on git/github, because git/github doesn't allow css styling.

**OBS!**: 
Using the code-element for highlighting is not semantic.
However, it is a possible solution for adding grey-colored highlighting to text in markdown.

### Markdown/HTML

```
<code> <i>This text will be italic</i> <b>this text will be bold</b> </code>
```

### Output

`This text will be italic this text will be bold`

Answer (score 4):

[Roam](https://roamresearch.com) markdown uses double-caret: `^^highlight^^`. Andrew Shell's answer mentions double-equals.

The accepted and clearly correct answer is `<mark>` from Matthias above, but I thought I had seen carets in some other flavor of markdown. Maybe not. I want to transform my `^^highlights^^` to `<mark>highlights</mark>` in pandoc conversion to html, and somehow ended up here...

Answer (score -7):

Probably best bet is just use html e.g

```html
<b>Hello</b> is higlighted
```

```
Hello is higlighted
```

Remember nearly all html is valid in markdown too.

Comment: Then using a `span` with a background would make more sense ... **Bold** is already in Markdown.